# Kentico: JSON serialization not escaping quotation marks

Tags: json, escaping, kentico

Is there a way to force the Kentico CMS JSON serializer to escape quotation marks properly?

Today I was helping my wife debug a text-cleanup routine, and in some cases the users had created HTML anchor tags in which the href target was surrounded by quotes. The resulting JSON was invalid, similar to this:

```
"news" : "some text <a href="foo.html">click here</a> more text"
```

Obviously the extra set of quotes around "foo.html" are going to prevent correct parsing of the JSON data value. I assume they should be escaped with a slash: \"

I'm not familiar with Kentico, but I'm wondering if there might be a switch somewhere?

Comment: Which version of Kentico CMS do you use and what do you mean by JSON serializer, the `ToJSON` extension methods?